# Find a string of text in an element and wrap some span tags round it

Tags: jquery, string, text

I want to find a string of text in an element and wrap some span tags round it. E.g.

From:

```
<h2>We have cows on our farm</h2>
```

To:

```
<h2>We have <span class='smallcaps'>cows</span> on our farm</h2>
```

I've tried:

```
$("h2:contains('cow')").each(function() {
 $(this).text().wrap("<span class='smallcaps'></span>");
});
```

But that only wraps the whole containing `h2` tag.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
$("h2:contains('cow')").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(/(cow)/g, '<span class="smallcaps">$1</span>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w5ze6/1/

Comment: I'm asking because I'm interested - Where can I find some documentation on the syntax that you're using? Specifically the `function(_ , html)` .

Comment: @Evan I think the best one is jQuery documentation, http://api.jquery.com/html/, as of jQuery 1.4, `html` method accepts a function, the first parameter is index and the second one is html content.

Comment: Yes, I saw that - but you can simply supply `_` as the index like that? Is it basically just sending a null index?

Comment: @Evan `_` like `$` is a valid character for defining identifiers in JavaScript. it's not `null`. There is also a JavaScript library named underscore http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Note that this will not work if you have some markup containing _cow_ inside the element. Like `<div><a href="cows">Click here</a></div>`. This will break the attribute.

Comment: @PhilippMichael That's a good point. Not only "cow" but every string that has "cow" segment in it.

Comment: I'm struggeling with this issue. Any idea how to improve your solution?

Comment: @PhilippMichael This is one of the simplest options. Another option is using a plugin or a solution that iterates through the nodes and only targets text nodes. [Here is a jQuery plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html).

Comment: But if I want to unwrap the text again then how can do that?

Answer (score 17):

Another approach, split by keyword and join with the updated html.

```
$("h2:contains('cow')").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.split('cow').join("<span class='smallcaps'>cow</span>");
});
```

Note: I haven't tested this, but I'm assuming this would perform worse than doing a replace, but figure I would include anyways for informative purposes

Comment: Thanks, the one above was failing when there were html tags around the keyword to begin with. This works perfectly. Nice to have an alternative.

Comment: I know it's several years down the line, but I've created a working fiddle for this answer.... http://jsfiddle.net/v2nqu05o/

Comment: works perfectly! Tried the accepted answer and it made my title disappear haha! this one worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a variation on @undefined's answer, which loops through an array of items:

```
var barnyardArray = [
    'cow',
    'horse',
    'chicken',
    'hog',
    'goat',
    'goose',
    'duck',
    'llama'
];

$.each(barnyardArray, function (index, value) {
    $("p:contains(" + value + ")").html(function (_, html) {
        var regex = new RegExp(value, 'g');
        return html.replace(regex, '<span class="smallcaps">' + value + '</span>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You usually want to match some arbitrary text in a case insensitive way. Sometimes, search queries contain characters that are special regex metacharacters and must be escaped before compiling the pattern.

Use a solution like

```js
var words = ["cows", "c++", "$var$"];
$("h2").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(new RegExp(words.map(function(x) { 
       return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
     }).join('|'), "gi"), '<span class="smallcaps">$&</span>')
});
```

```css
span { color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>We have cows on our farm</h2>
<h2>C++ Apps $var$</h2>
```

Note that here, a regex will look like `/cows|c\+\+|\$var\$/gi`, where `+` and `$`, [**special regex metacharacters**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), are escaped, and the alternatives are ORed with the `|` [**alternation operator**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Also, note that there is no need of any outer parentheses as the default group is Group 0 that holds the whole match, and the backreference to Group 0 in JavaScript regex is `$&`. Thus, the replacement is always done with the search word in the exact case as it was found in text.

Note that in case you need to match *whole words only*, you would need special boundaries, either `\b` (if the search words always consist of letters, digits or `_`) or `(\W|^)` / `(?!\w)` (if there can be special characters):

```js
var words = ["cows", "c++", "$var$"];
$("h2").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(new RegExp("(\\W|^)(" + words.map(function(x) { 
       return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
     }).join('|') + ")(?!\\w)", "gi"), '$1<span class="smallcaps">$2</span>')
});
```

```css
span { color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>We have cows in our farm cowshed</h2>
<h2>C++ Apps $var$ in $var$moretext</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have some tag inside the target div and some text i need to wrap that text into a link.

This how i did following "What have you tried".

```
var oldText = $(this).text(),
newText = $(this).html().replace(
    oldText, 
    "<a class='k-link' href='#' class='smallcaps'>" + 
        oldText + 
    "<span class='k-icon k-i-arrow-n'></span></a>"
);
$(this).html(newText);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("h2:contains('cow')").each(function() {
    var newText = $(this).html().replace("cow", "<span class='smallcaps'></span>");
    $(this).html(newText);
});
```

Comment: you should change it to set the html of the element, not the text

Comment: This is replacing the keyword instead of wrapping it