# Identify a text using jquery and warp it insde a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code

```
<form method="get" name="form_delivery">

  Please select country for delivery<br>

  <select name="deliverymethod">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select country / region</option>
    <option value="1">UK (incl. Northern Ireland)</option>
    <option value="8">Australia</option>
    <option value="9">New Zealand</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

I need to identify the text "Please select country for delivery" and wrap it around the container like a "span" and replace the wrapped text

```
<form method="get" name="form_delivery">

   <span>Please select country for delivery</span><br>
```

This code is generated by an automated server, I only have access to HTML Template hence Jquery is the only option for making modifications on the fly.

Any Idea's?

Comment: Have a look here, this is very similar -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090487/find-a-string-of-text-in-an-element-and-wrap-some-span-tags-round-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions here :

**1 :** If you don't have any binding on other elements of the form, you may simply do a replace of the HTML :

```
$('form').html(function(_,h){
     var t = "Please select country for delivery";
     return h.replace(t, '<span>'+t+'</span>');
});
```

**2 :** If you have bindings, you can't do that as it would delete all elements, you need to do it cleanly, not modifying other elements. You may use a library for that like my own [groumf](https://github.com/Canop/groumf) :

```
Groumf.replaceTextWithHTMLInHTML(document.body, t, function(s){
    return '<span>'+t+'</span>'
});
```

Comment: I like the Groumf code but it adds a dependency of another library.  On the first solution what does the '_' do on the index position? I am just curious to know.

Comment: `_` is just a variable name chosen to look like a place-holder. You might have used `i` instead. It's just an habit I took from other languages where you can specify `_` where you don't want to use a variable.

Comment: Interesting...!! the first solution removed some binding it seems, the select's on change event is not firing for some reason. But thanks for the answer, I can take it from where you stopped. I learned something new.

Comment: @ClainDsilva Another solution would be to not have any direct binding but only use validation (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-method-not-working-on-dynamic-content) ).

Comment: Binding are made from a pre build script that is executed on dom ready. I am writing a parallel script on custom script file which is loaded along with the template. Thanks for the pointer , that was really useful

Comment: I am Accepting your answer as it have the best insights to the problem most certainly guided me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the text is the first part of the form, you can use `$($('form').get(0).childNodes[0]).wrap('<span>');`.

Comment: Interesting but I need text match code , but your code gave me some insights

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contents()` to get the text nodes as well as the HTML elements using jQuery. You can then filter out the text nodes, using `.filter()` (which might be unnecessary, depending on your potential markup) and then get what I'm assuming will always be the first text node, using `.eq()`.

From there we can wrap this text node in a `<span>` using `.wrap()`, traverse to this new `<span>`, and prepend it to our form:

```
var $form = $('form[name=form_delivery]')
$form.contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).eq(0).wrapAll('<span></span>').closest('span').prependTo($form);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pr7kydxy/1/)

Comment: I guess this needs a extra function that search for the text and identify the node then apply the wrap. The code is mostly like a guess.

Comment: This code will wrap the first text node it finds in a span, I may have misunderstood the question?

Comment: Probably yes..!! I need to find the text and do a span warp

Comment: In that case see the first half of [dystroy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27123466/1612146).