# Change the text size as resulting string a PHP function

Tags: php, html, css

I am with a doubt in CSS I have a string ex: R$3,055.00 and was wondering how do I get to the "R$" of the word and just let the smaller font than the rest of the word.

I have this function in PHP that returns the value of a product:

```
  <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Now I'm working trentando her CSS with this code::

```
.regular-price .price {
    color: #0075BD !important;
    font-size: 30px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
.price::before{

    content: 'R$';
    font-size: 0.7em;

}
```

Comment: If the function returns a value, need to change the css that the function returned.
Do not want to harm anyone might not know how to express myself, sorry.

Comment: ried to change the description of my question with informing the code and why I'm using it, I have not changed to discredit the help of anyone, I'm just trying to be clearer as I was asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do, as other answers have noted, need to place that string into an element in order to target it with CSS. Assuming that the `R$` is purely presentational, then I'd suggest the following, using a `::before` pseudo-element to place the `R$` text and style it appropriately:

```css
span.price::before {
  content: 'R$';
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<span class="price">3,055.00</span>
```

Based on the updated question, I'd suggest (using the above CSS HTML):

```
<?php echo '<span class="price">' . str_replace('R$', '', $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)) . '</span>'; ?>
// 'R$': the string we're looking to replace, the 'needle';
// '': the string we're looking to replace with;
// $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true): the string we're looking in,
// the 'haystack'
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Compatibility for `::before` and `::after`](http://caniuse.com/#search=before).
  - [CSS pseudo-elements, `::before`/`::after`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#before-and-after).
  - [Generated content, automatic numbering, and lists: The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content).
- PHP:

  - [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use eg. `small` for that.

```
<style>
#price {font-size: 12px;}
#price small {font-size: 10px;}
</style>

<p id="price">
    <small>R$</small>3,055.00
</p>
```

Comment: If is a string he must do it with javascript to add span to R$, and then use your style - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090487/find-a-string-of-text-in-an-element-and-wrap-some-span-tags-round-it

Answer (score 0):

You must change the html markup like this

```
<p class='price'><span>R$</span>3,055.00</p>
```

And then you can stylise like this :

```
.price{
   //Price style here
}
.price span{
  // Intro styles here like :
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

Hope to help

Comment: unfortunately I can not do so because I get the value of a function of "Magento" example, getPrice () al returns me the entire string.  =(