# Add css style to a specific text using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

How to add style to a particular text or characters within a div?

```
<div class="test">blocks of texts here.</div>
```

I want to add color to the word "texts" without using any tags such as span to enclose it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not possible without wrapping specific text/character(s). But then, why not wrapping it?

Comment: For people down voting, I think its obvious this user is new. If you down vote you should typically try to explain what the user did wrong or link to some help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you explain *why* you don’t want the enclose the words you want to highlight?

Comment: To save more time and markup when posting an article. I'm just curious if this is possible with jquery. I only knew css. thanks for your replies.

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically wrap a specific text using jquery? I'm afraid, NOT also ...

Comment: This is possibly a good solution >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090487/find-a-string-of-text-in-an-element-and-wrap-some-span-tags-round-it. It will dynamically wrap a specific text then just add css the normal way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that without wrapping the text to an element. But you can do the wrapping with jQuery:

```
var $test = $('.test').html();
$test = $test.replace(/texts/gi, '<span class="tomato">texts</span>');
$('.test').html($test);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r36xjzs7/

This will recreate the whole element though, so it's not that efficient.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to target more than one word?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following **function** to style any word in text:

```
function style_word(text_id, word, css_style) {
    html = $('#' + text_id).html();
    replace = word;
    re = new RegExp(replace,"gi");
    $('#' + text_id).html(html.replace(re, "<span style='" + css_style + "'>" + word + "</span>"));
    }
```

Simply *target* the element that contains the text, choosing the *word* to style and the css *styling* of choice.

Here is an **example**:

```
<div id='my_words'>
There is little doubt that stack overflow has become the de facto method of building software. There is no other way to ensure we are not reinventing the wheel, and benefiting from the power of massive collaboration and variation. A network of contributing individuals will always produce the most optimal solution, and this cannot be matched by the singular efforts of an individual.
</div>
```

**Usage**:

```
style_word('my_words', 'software', 'color: hotpink')
```

**Results:**

[image]

```
style_word('my_words', 'software', 'font-style: italic')
```

[image]

It also supports passing **multiple styles** in one call:

```
style_word('my_words', 'software', 'font-size: 24px; color: blue; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally would wrap the words within a span element.

```
<div class="test">blocks of <span id="blueText">texts</span> here.</div>
```

Then you can call

```
$("#blueText").css('color', 'blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't.

But it ***is*** a good question: *aaronk6* asked why wouldn't you wrap the word in a span, and the reason is that CSS is a tool to separate content and appearance, so this is *precisely* what it should be used for. Also, you might find yourself in a situation where you can edit the CSS but has no access to the html.

[There's a great article by Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/) on this issue, calling for some extra CSS selectors that would come in handy for that.

That being said, the solution by *Cybernetic* is great (kudos)! If you are to make such alterations in the file, and can't (or won't) touch the html, javascript is the way to go. But instead of hardcoding the CSS rules, I propose you just give it a span with a class, and make the rules in your external CSS file. The code would go:

```
function style_word(text_element, word_to_style) {
    html = text_element.html();
    classID = "style-"+word_to_style;
    re = new RegExp(word_to_style,"gi");
    new_html = html.replace(re, "<span class='"+classID+"'>"+word_to_style+"</span>");
    text_element.html(new_html);
    }
```

So, if you wanted to change only "bar" in `<p>foo bar</p>`, you'd call:

```
style_word( $("p"), "bar" ); //jQuery element, then word inside
```

And then add a CSS rule:

```
.style-bar{
    color: #123;
}
```

PS.: Sorry this is not a comment on Cybernetic post... I'm not allowed to comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me...

```
var textcontent="";
$("p").each(function(){
if ($(this).html().indexOf("THESTRING") >= 0)
{
var textcontent = $(this).html().replace(/THESTRING/gi, '<span class="tomato">THESTRING</span>');
$(this).html(textcontent);
    
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".test").css("color","white");
```

Comment: That'd be applied to all the text, not only specific word(s)