# How can I iterate over every word in an element and then conditionally wrap matches?

Tags: jquery, html, replace, each, contains

I'm writing on my own blog in ASP.NET and I'm using [Gist embed](https://github.com/blairvanderhoof/gist-embed) for my code-blocks. I'd like to color the code to match how a particular language appears in it's IDE. Specifically Swift in Xcode.

I started with a jsFiddle and have gotten to the point of selecting "var" and turning it red, but the example I found for iterating over words and wrapping them uses a **return** value which breaks the loop.

**update:** the return statement which I found here, causes a syntax error. I adapted the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090487/find-a-string-of-text-in-an-element-and-wrap-some-span-tags-round-it), and would be happy to explore alternatives.

### How can I iterate over every word on the screen and conditionally wrap them?

I'm able to match on one word but I cant find a way to continue the operation. For the sake of simplicity lets only look for two words, **var** & **override**.

my code:

```
var line = $('.line');

$.each(line, function(i, val){
   var value = $('.line').text();

    $("*:contains('var')").html(function(_, html) {

        return html.replace(/(var)/g, '<span style="color:red;">$1</span>');
    });

    $("*:contains('override')").html(function(_, html) {

        return html.replace(/(override)/g, '<span style="color:blue;">$1</span>');
    });
});
```

my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91xrosxa/2/).

Comment: Did you open the console ?

Comment: I've been working with the console open, I'm new to jQuery so I usually work based off positive feedback from console.logs.

Comment: syntax error, my only guess is that its the (_, html)

Comment: There's seems to be an issue with what is returned to the `html` function ?

Comment: I've updated my post to include a link to reference where I found the code I adapted.

Comment: Also, the replacements are to large, `*` matches everything, and the outer elements contain the same elements multiple times, so the replacements happens multiple times etc. You should somehow filter down the elements to only get elements with no children, and then do the replacement on those

Comment: for example $('.line:contains('var')')? EDIT: I think this just solved my issue

Comment: No, more like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/91xrosxa/3/

Comment: that code makes way more sense... thank you adeneo

Comment: @adeneo - can you post that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loop that iterates over each line, and inside that loop you fetch all elements containing a word in every iteration, making the replacement run *a lot* of times.

Do the iteration once, and it can be done with a callback to `html()` as it iterates iternally, and do the replacements in the same loop

```
$('.line').html(function(_, html) {
    html = html.replace(/(var)/g, '<span style="color:red;">$1</span>');
    html = html.replace(/(override)/g, '<span style="color:blue;">$1</span>');

    return html;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/91xrosxa/7/)