# Wrap index of character in string in span tag with class javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element with a string like this:

```
<p>I like trains and planes</p>
```

I get it's text with jQuery `.text()` and save it in a string.

```
var str = $('p').text();
```

I want to find for example the "k" with `str[5]` and replace the inner HTML of `<p>` to wrap it around a `<span>` tag with the class "red" for example. So I can style it. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090487/find-a-string-of-text-in-an-element-and-wrap-some-span-tags-round-it#) solution but its answer uses a regex, and I want the letter to add a span wrap to be variable.

How can I achieve this?

PS: I want to for example change this:

```
<p>I like trains and planes</p>
```

to this:

```
<p>I li<span class="red">k</span>e trains and planes</p>
```

But I don't want to find the "k", because they may be a lot of "k" characters, I want to find the character number `x` in the element.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with your var `str` and index `x`:

```
$('p').html(str.slice(0, x) + '<span class="red">' + str[x] + '</span>' + str.slice(x + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var getletter = $('p').text().charAt(4);
var newletter = '<span class="red">'+getletter+'</span>';
//alert(newletter);
var replace_it = $('p').text().replace(getletter , newletter);
//alert(replace_it);
$('p').html(replace_it);
```

```css
.red{
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>I like trains and planes</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but replace will replace the first ocurrence, and if the letter is common (i.e: letter e), it will replace the first e and not the one I want ( it may be the third e in the string)

Comment: @ALSDMinecraft by charAt(4) you just determine the letter number 5 cause charAt starts from 0 .. you can change it as you like ... in my answer I worked with letter index  not the spill of letter K or e

Comment: @ALSDMinecraft, you can use this answer as you expect by just changing `.replace()` to `replaceAt()`.