# div / bold contains text give class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a *loot* box div in which (sometimes) the name *colorful* comes in. 
for example:

```
<div id="columns">
<div id="loot">
<b>
"Loot: Colorful blade "
<br>
" slot: weapon "
<br>
" value: 7"
</b>
...more and more and more
```

Now **if** the text in the *loot* div *contains* `colorful` I want to *add*  a class to the text *colorful* . So I thought that **if** the text *colorful* is in it, it puts a `<span>` around the word *colorful* and asign a *class*  to it. But I cant figure out how to do this.

I tried [this (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/o7phybe8/)

Comment: your code works, you simply didn't have the jquery loaded in that fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/o7phybe8/1/

Comment: I dont want the _entire_ div to be _rainbow_ just the text _colorful_ @gurvinder372

Comment: A span around *just* the word 'Colorful', and apply a class-name to that span, or add the class-name to the whole `<div>`?

Comment: Will close this as duplicate .. [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16090562/2887133)  ..and your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o7phybe8/4/

Comment: I want to add a span around the word 'Colorful' and apply a class-name to that span , but I cant hardcore it because it is not _always_ 'Colorful'  @DavidThomas

Comment: How can it work on the fiddle but not in my own code @DaniP

Comment: Could be many things .... wrong selector ? wrong vinculation of .js files ? any console errors ? can you replicate that issue?

Comment: no error @DaniP http://i.imgur.com/tf0EvZr.png / http://i.imgur.com/LbqkKAa.png

Comment: Try to execute the function on document ready copy this code https://jsfiddle.net/o7phybe8/5/

Comment: thats not the problem @DaniP already got `(function() {` but maybe because the _content_ of the div is loaded in in JavaScript / Jquery (thats why I use the `setTimeout`

Comment: @DaniP you know how to fix this?

Comment: You may need try to replicate the creation of content in jsfiddle ... the way to solve this it's execute the function righ after the content is created

Comment: thanks @DaniP it worked :) I added it _right_ after the content is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Your code targets the #loot element when trying to add the rainbow class, but does it target the desired div when looking for the text in the first place? (I dont think it does, but dunno since I dont jQuery)

Here's some code to do it sans jQuery:

```
var tgtElem = document.getElementById('loot');
var value = tgtElem.innerHTML;
value = value.replace('Colorful', '<span class="highlight">Colorful</span>');
tgtElem.innerHTML = value;
```

It relies upon a css rule, `.highlight` - set its styles as you wish.

Here's a fully worked example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    var tgtElem = byId('loot');
    var value = tgtElem.innerHTML;
    value = value.replace('Colorful', '<span class="highlight">Colorful</span>');
    tgtElem.innerHTML = value;
}
</script>
<style>
.highlight
{
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="columns">
        <div id="loot">
            <b>
            Loot: Colorful blade 
            <br>
             slot: weapon 
            <br>
             value: 7
            </b>
            <br />
            <br />
            <b>Current slot: weapon <br> Current weapon :  Colorful blade  <br> Current value: 7</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't make it seem to work. Not in my code, or in Jsfiddle

Comment: JSfiddle has changed recently. I can no longer find an option to put the JS into the head, without wrapping it in anything. This prevents the `onDocLoaded` function from firing. I also note that you've probably got more than 1 instance to replace - in this case, my code will fail, only replacing the first one. To get all instances, you'll need to use a regular expression - essentially, this means wrapping the replacement text with forward slashes (I think, I forget) and then appending a `g` after the expression. It's also fairly easy to change into a function so you could highlight any word

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to the libary for the jQuery to work.

You can get it here https://code.jquery.com/

You were also correct with using the span around the word. Here is a working version

```
Loot: <span>Colorful</span> blade
```

Then target it to add the class

```
    if ($('#loot:contains("Colorful")').length > 0) {

     var str = document.getElementById("loot").innerHTML; 
     var res = str.replace("Colorful", "<span>Colorful</span>");
     document.getElementById("loot").innerHTML = res;

     $("#loot span").addClass("rainbow");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o7phybe8/6/

Comment: If you are looking for a more dynamic approach I would recommend enhzflep code

Comment: What if a different div on the page - i.e one other than #loot contains the word Colorful? Is it still the intention to style the instance of the word (if it exists) in the #loot element?

Comment: `Colorful` isn't always in there, so I cant hardcore a `span` around it, because it is not there _yet_  and maybe it will not be _there_

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more useful one addressing some of these problems