# Jquery- Find a word in a sentence and add span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a function to find word in a sentences and add span on top. This is the code but it is not working. Can anyone point out my mistake? Thanks

```js
  function find_and_add(element = "", findWord = "") {
      $(element).each(function() {
        var arr = $('h1 a', this).text().split(' ');
        var newTitle = "";
        $.each(arr ,function(key, value) {
          if (value == findWord) {
            newTitle += "<span>"+ value + "</span><br/>";
          } else {
            newTitle += value + " ";
          }
        });
        $("h1 a", this).html(newTitle);
      });
    }
    
    find_and_add('.wrapper', 'BMW');
    find_and_add('.wrapper', 'Toyota');
    find_and_add('.wrapper', 'Ferrari');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <h1> 
     <a href="#"> Brand name BMW </a>
  </h1>
  <h1> 
     <a href="#"> Brand name Toyota </a>
  </h1>
  <h1> 
     <a href="#"> Brand name Ferrari </a>
  </h1>
 
</div>
```

Comment: There should be a fine to be paid when someone just says "my code is not working" :) What is your code doing wrong? or what is it not doing at all?

Comment: You are missing a dot: `find_and_add('.wrapper', 'BMW');`

Comment: You are missing a dot :)

Comment: ANd there is a lot more wrong than just the dot.

Comment: Might I suggest string.replace with regex instead of splitting and manually iterating over the words. It doesn't fix your issue, but simplifies the code which will make it easier to identify the issue.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne `text = text.replace(new RegExp(value,"g"), '<span class="red">' + value + "</span>");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a string of text in an element and wrap some span tags round it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090487/find-a-string-of-text-in-an-element-and-wrap-some-span-tags-round-it)

Comment: ok. Thanks missing a dot in wrapper was my typing mistake :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of things wrong with your code.

You need a dot before a class name

```
find_and_add('.wrapper', 'BMW');
```

You're passing in the parent wrapper and then trying to find one specific word in a bunch of children in a really convoluted manner. Why not pass in the parent and the list of search terms as per the example below.

```js
function find_and_add(element = "", findWords = "") {
      $(element).find("h1 a").each(function() {
       var $elem = $(this); 
        var arr = $elem.text().split(' ');
        var newTitle = "";
        $.each(arr ,function(key, value) {
          if (findWords.indexOf(value)>-1) {
            newTitle += "<span>"+ value + "</span><br/>";
          } else {
            newTitle += value + " ";
          }
        });
        $elem.html(newTitle);
      });
    }
    
    find_and_add('.wrapper', ['BMW','Toyota','Ferrari']);
```

```css
span{
  background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <h1> 
     <a href="#"> Brand name BMW </a>
  </h1>
  <h1> 
     <a href="#"> Brand name Toyota </a>
  </h1>
  <h1> 
     <a href="#"> Brand name Ferrari </a>
  </h1>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the jsfiddle that is working for the question below

https://jsfiddle.net/princedc/mg7bkeas/

I am processing every thing on one function call this will ensure better performance. I pass all the words to be changed with one function call. The substitution you are making has to be changed as we need to replace the element alone $(this) in jquery.

```
function find_and_add(element = "", findWord = "") {
          var lookUpWords = findWord.split(' ');
      $(element).each(function() {
        var arr = $('h1 a', this);
        //console.log(arr);

        $.each(arr ,function(key, value) {
          debugger;
            console.log(value);
          var newTitle = "";
          var words = value.text.split(' ');
          $.each(words,function(wkey,wvalue){
             if (lookUpWords.indexOf(wvalue) >= 0) {
              newTitle += "<span>"+ wvalue + "</span><br/>";
            } else {
              newTitle += wvalue + " ";
            }

          });
         $(this).html(newTitle);

        });
        //$("h1 a", this).html('').html(newTitle);
      });
    }

    find_and_add('.wrapper', 'BMW Toyota Ferrari');
    //find_and_add('.wrapper', 'Toyota');
    //find_and_add('.wrapper', 'Ferrari');
```