# Get HTML Text that has no tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to access a piece of text inside a DIV that has no HTML through jquery (In this case the words "12 Months"). I know that I could find it if I knew the class or id, but in this case it seems it has no way to be grabbed. Can somebody provide a potential solution?

```
<div class="pms-subscription-plan">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="subscription_plans" data-price="19.99" data-duration="12" value="1219">$19.99 cada 12 meses</label>
<span class="pms-divider"> - </span><span class="pms-subscription-plan-price">19.99</span>
<span class="pms-subscription-plan-currency">$</span>
<span class="pms-divider"> / </span> 12 Months //This piece of text is the one I need to get and change
<div class="pms-subscription-plan-description">Si usted escogió la suscripción $19.99, se le cobrará por esa cantidad anualmente.</div>
</div>
```

If it helps, here's a printout of the code as seen in the inspector.

[image]

Comment: What you want to do with it?

Comment: @mr.void Either Hide it or change it.

Comment: $('label').text();

Comment: First answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090487/find-a-string-of-text-in-an-element-and-wrap-some-span-tags-round-it solves this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works!

```js
var a = $('.pms-subscription-plan').first().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();

console.log($.trim(a));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pms-subscription-plan">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="subscription_plans" data-price="19.99" data-duration="12" value="1219">$19.99 cada 12 meses</label>
  <span class="pms-divider"> - </span><span class="pms-subscription-plan-price">19.99</span>
  <span class="pms-subscription-plan-currency">$</span>
  <span class="pms-divider"> / </span> 12 Months
  <div class="pms-subscription-plan-description">Si usted escogió la suscripción $19.99, se le cobrará por esa cantidad anualmente.</div>
</div>
```

**But you have to be sure that you don't restructure.**

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $(".pms-subscription-plan").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the following code will work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pms-divider")[1].nextSibling
```

HOWEVER, I would strongly recommend putting this text in a tag. This code will not work if you in any way restructure your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML there are elements and nodes. Each piece of text is a node. You can use the `childNodes` collection.

```
var textNode = document.querySelector(".pms-subscription-plan").childNodes[9].data.trim();
```

Comment: That will get "*$19.99 cada 12 meses*" rather than "*12 Months*", which is not a childnode of the **`label`**

Comment: Thanks for the info, I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You could, as others have suggested, use the node/next sibling to get the text.

However, it would be a much better option to make a small adjustment to your html/css such as this:

```
<div class="pms-subscription-plan">

<label>
<input type="radio" name="subscription_plans" data-price="19.99" data-duration="12" value="1219">$19.99 cada 12 meses</label>
<span class="pms-divider"> - </span><span class="pms-subscription-plan-price">19.99</span>
<span class="pms-subscription-plan-currency">$</span>
<span class="pms-divider">/</span> 
<span class="pms-duration">12 Months</span>  <!--add a span class for duration--->
<div class="pms-subscription-plan-description">Si usted escogió la suscripción $19.99, se le cobrará por esa cantidad anualmente.</div>
</div>
```

and this small change [adding a span class for the duration] would make it easier for you in the long run. Just my tuppence!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This function will remove all the tags and content. What's left is the text you require:

```
function removeTags(){
  var txt = $(".pms-subscription-plan").html();
  var rex = /(<([^>]+)>).*(<([^>]+)>)|(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
  alert(txt.replace(rex , ""));
}
```